# Best way to make accessible api with es6 modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm writing a browser api with es6 (translated with babel). Since other js are going to call my api, I need to make my api accessible from the global (*window*) scope.

With module pattern in plain js (es5) I would have done something like this:

*myApp.js*

```
var myApp = (function(){
    var a, b, c;
    function setA(){
        // set a
    }

    // other functions
    return {
        "setA": setA,
        // ... other functions
    };
}());
```

*myAppExt.js*

```
window.myApp = window.myApp || {};
(function(app){
    app.Module1 = (function(){
        return {
            // methods of this module
        };
    }());
}(myApp));
```

With es6 we're not supposed to do something like this but to achieve the same objective I'm writing my app in this way:

*myApp.js*

```
import method1 from './common/module1.js'
import init from './folder/init.js'
import {method2, method3} from './folder/module2.js'
import log from './common/log.js'

const myApp = {};
window.myApp = myApp;

myApp.method1 = method1;
myApp.method2 = method2;
myApp.method3 = method3;
myApp.log = log;

init();
```

Is this the best way to achieve this goal or is there any better design solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are going to develop a library you will probably end up generating one single bundled file which contains all the contents of your library. To create a a a bundle you need a tool like `webpack` or `browserify`, both tools allow you to create your library in a way that can be consumed in many ways (`AMD`, `CommonJS`, `global`...).

So you need to create a root module:

### myLibrary.js

```
import something from './framework/module1.js';
import somethingElse from './framework/module2.js';

// export public parts of your library
export {something};
export {somethingElse };
```

Then use `webpack` **library** setting:

```
{
    output: {
        // export itself to a global var
        libraryTarget: "var",
        // name of the global var: "Foo"
        library: "Foo"
    },
    externals: {
        // require("jquery") is external and available
        //  on the global var jQuery
        "jquery": "jQuery"
    }
}
```

More info [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html).

You can also use `browserify` **standalone** setting:

> --standalone -s  Generate a UMD bundle for the supplied export name.
>                      This bundle works with other module systems and sets the name
>                      given as a window global if no module system is found.

More info [here](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. It fits exactly with my environment since I'm using webpack.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually merged the solution proposed from OweR ReLoaDeD with another I've found.

After configuring webpack to export global variable, instead of importing and then exporting methods I've exported directly what I needed to be available in the public api.

```
export {method} from './common/file1.js'; 
export * from './dir/file2.js' 
export {anothermethod} from './common/file2.js
```

Thank you for the help